# File corruption when returning document with send_file from Flask dockerized for Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, docker, flask, aws-lambda, file-transfer

I dockerized a basic Flask application for use on AWS Lambda. The Flask code works as expected when ran locally but returns a corrupted file when used from a deployed Lambda function.

Any suggestions, fixes, or even insight as to what could be going wrong in this situation would be much appreciated.

I have attempted several ways of reading the target file and passing it to send file but the returned file is always corrupt (current way shown below). Passing the file directly from a directory results in the same outcome. I also attempted zipping the file and returning a .zip, but that appears to be corrupt as well.

```py
with open(target_file, "rb") as fh:
     buf = BytesIO(fh.read())
     buf.seek(0)
     return send_file(buf, mimetype="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", as_attachment=True, download_name=file_name, max_age=0)
```

I have also attempted to read the file immediately prior to sending it by opening and reading directly from it to see if the stored file is already corrupt. The file is read perfectly but the returned document is unreadible.

Difference in the files when open in VS Code with a text editor
Binary view of corrupt file in VS Code:
[image: Binary view of corrupt file in VS Code]

Binary view of valid file in VS Code:
[image: Binary view of valid file in VS Code]

Other details:

- The docker image is Amazon Linux, architecture: linux/arm64.
- The file that is being sent is generated by python and saved in "tmp/" as this appears to be the only place Lambda allows write access.